# Getting "Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception"

Tags: 7, commerce

I tried to install module `Commerce Event Ticket`, added all the requirements, then enabled `Commerce Event Ticket` and got an error message:

```
Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;base.owner&#039; in &#039;field list&#039;: SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.owner AS owner, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1 ) in EntityAPIController->query() (line 187 of /home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).

Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;base.owner&#039; in &#039;field list&#039;: SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.owner AS owner, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1 ) in EntityAPIController->query() (line 187 of /home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.controller.inc).
```

Now, this message also appears on the page without admin rights i.e. my page is  **Offline** now! How can I fix this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Start by [installing drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/1791676) (if you haven't already) and running `drush cc all` from your site/mysite directory. This clears all caches.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, try `drush dis commerce_event_ticket` to disable the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after this error, I ran `www.mysite/update.php` it applied a few updates after which I was able to access the admin pages but if i wanted to access my front page, I'd still get

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_info_field_map() in /home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.tokens.inc on line 92**

instead. I then removed the module `addressfield` by ftp manually and my site was back up and running so that I can care about my module(s)  separately.